# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null objectStack in test class

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

I am trying to write a test class for this apex class and VF page but im getting this error .Apex class and VF Page without error and working fine.
`System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null objectStack TraceClass.Custom_Account_Lookup_Search.saveAccount: line 42, column 1
Class.Test_Custom_Account_Lookup_Search.test1: line 24, column 1`
 how to solve this issue;

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest(Seealldata = true)
public class Test_Custom_Account_Lookup_Search {
    Static testmethod void test1() {
        PageReference pg = page.Custom_Account_Lookup_Search_page;
        Test.setcurrentPage(pg);
        //account a = new Account( name='foo' ,BillingStreet ='west',BillingCity ='test') ;
        //insert a;
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'voltum';
        acc.BillingStreet = 'Santhom High Road';
        acc.BillingCity = 'Chennai';
        acc.BillingState = 'TamilNadu';
        acc.BillingCountry = 'India';
        //acc.BillingZipPostal='6000028';
        acc.Email__c = 'perisoft@voltum.com';
        acc.Fax = '+49 9134 85 28732';
        acc.Website = 'http://www.voltum.com.au/';
        insert acc;
        Site__c site = new Site__c();
        ApexPages.StandardController stdController1 = new ApexPages.StandardController(site);
        Custom_Account_Lookup_Search thecontroller1 = new Custom_Account_Lookup_Search(stdController1);
        thecontroller1.saveAccount();

    }
}
```

**Aex class:**

```
public with sharing class Custom_Account_Lookup_Search {

    public Account account {get; set;} // new account to create
    public List<Account> results {get; set;} // search results
    public string searchString {get; set;} // search keyword

    public Custom_Account_Lookup_Search() {
        account = new Account();
        // get the current search string
        searchString = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('lksrch');
        runSearch();
    }

    // performs the keyword search
    public PageReference search() {
        runSearch();
        return null;
    }
    public Custom_Account_Lookup_Search(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    }
    // prepare the query and issue the search command
    private void runSearch() {
        // TODO prepare query string for complex serarches & prevent injections
        results = performSearch(searchString);
    }

    // run the search and return the records found.
    private List<Account> performSearch(string searchString) {

        String soql = 'select id, name from account';
        if (searchString != '' && searchString != null)
            soql = soql + ' where name LIKE \'%' + searchString + '%\'';
        soql = soql + ' limit 25';
        System.debug(soql);
        return database.query(soql);

    }

    // save the new account record
    public PageReference saveAccount() {
        insert account;
        // reset the account
        account = new Account();
        return null;
    }

    // used by the visualforce page to send the link to the right dom element
    public string getFormTag() {
        return System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('frm');
    }

    // used by the visualforce page to send the link to the right dom element for the text box
    public string getTextBox() {
        return System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('txt');
    }

}
```

**VF page**

```
<apex:page controller="Custom_Account_Lookup_Search"
    title="Search"
    showHeader="false"
    sideBar="false"
    tabStyle="Account"
    id="pg">

<apex:form >
    <apex:outputPanel id="page" layout="block" style="margin:5px;padding:10px;padding-top:2px;">
        <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name1" id="tabbedPanel">

        <!-- SEARCH TAB -->
        <apex:tab label="Search" name="tab1" id="tabOne">

            <apex:actionRegion >
                <apex:outputPanel id="top" layout="block" style="margin:5px;padding:10px;padding-top:2px;">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Search" style="font-weight:Bold;padding-right:10px;" for="txtSearch"/>
                    <apex:inputText id="txtSearch" value="{!searchString}" />
                    <span style="padding-left:5px"><apex:commandButton id="btnGo" value="Go" action="{!Search}" rerender="searchResults"></apex:commandButton></span>
                </apex:outputPanel>                    
                <apex:outputPanel id="pnlSearchResults" style="margin:10px;height:350px;overflow-Y:auto;" layout="block">
                    <apex:pageBlock id="searchResults">
                        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!results}" var="a" id="tblResults">
                            <apex:column >
                                <apex:facet name="header">
                                <apex:outputPanel >Name</apex:outputPanel>
                                </apex:facet>
                                <apex:outputLink value="javascript&colon;top.window.opener.lookupPick2('{!FormTag}','{!TextBox}_lkid','{!TextBox}','{!a.Id}','{!a.Name}', false)" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(a.Id))}">{!a.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                            </apex:column>
                        </apex:pageBlockTable>
                    </apex:pageBlock>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:actionRegion>

            </apex:tab>

            <!-- NEW ACCOUNT TAB -->
            <apex:tab label="New Account" name="tab2" id="tabTwo">

                <apex:pageBlock id="newAccount" title="New Account" >

                    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!saveAccount}" value="Save"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                    <apex:pageMessages />

                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                        <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account.FieldSets.CustomAccountLookup}" var="f">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Account[f]}"/>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:pageBlock>

        </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling the constructor that creates an instance of Account, you're calling the constructor that's used when the controller is used as an extension:

```
public Custom_Account_Lookup_Search(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
}
```

Going via this route means no Account is being created, and as such when you call the save method it's trying to insert `null`.

Make sure this constructor creates a new Account instance, but you'll also need to populate some fields to insert it.

Alternatively if you don't mean to be using this as an extension you should just call the other constructor:

```
// Site__c site = new Site__c();
// ApexPages.StandardController stdController1 = new ApexPages.StandardController(site);
Custom_Account_Lookup_Search thecontroller1 = new Custom_Account_Lookup_Search();
thecontroller1.saveAccount();
```

Note that even doing this still means that no fields have been populated on the account record and you'll likely need to set some (at least the Name).

Comment: thanks for reply LaceySnr,Please tell me where i need to change.

Comment: @LavanyaSanathkumar please see that LaceySnr pointed out that you need to add the constructor. Add the constructor to your controller.

Comment: please tell me am i doing right or wrong.
//add constructor// public Custom_Account_Lookup_Search(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    sap=(SAP_SD__)stdController.getRecord();}
//save
public PageReference saveAccount() {
    insert account;
    // reset the account
    account = new Account();
PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();
  pageRef.setRedirect(true);
  return pageRef; }